# fast generate a large set of random strings from number and alphabet

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, shuffle

I have to generate a **large** set (10k, and even more) of strings, which is of size 32 chars, randomly from "a-z", "A-Z", and "0-9".

So far, I have the following code (O(N*32)) in my mind, but I wonder if there are better ways to do that.

```
int N = 10000;           
vector<string> vecStr;

for (int index=0; index<N; index++)
{
  string str;
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
  {
    int randomChar = rand()%(26+26+10);        
    if (randomChar < 26)
      str += 'a' + randomChar;
    else if (randomChar < 26+26)
      str += 'A' + randomChar - 26;
    else
      str += '0' + randomChar - 26 - 26;
  }
  vecStr.push_back(str);
}
```

Comment: I would probably use [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) together with [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and the [C++11 PRNG functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). But all that would accomplish would be that the code maybe was a bit more C++ and less C, it would not really be more effective. Also, preallocate the vectors/strings might be a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not going to find a solution better than O(N*len), where N is the number of strings and len is the length of each therein. That said, somewhere I'm sure there is tarnished sticker I can earn for writing the *densest* code to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    static const char alphabet[] =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "0123456789";

    static const size_t N_STRS = 10000;
    static const size_t S_LEN = 32;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine rng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0,sizeof(alphabet)/sizeof(*alphabet)-2);

    std::vector<std::string> strs;
    strs.reserve(N_STRS);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(strs), strs.capacity(),
        [&] { std::string str; 
              str.reserve(S_LEN); 
              std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(str), S_LEN,
                   [&]() { return alphabet[dist(rng)];}); 
              return str; });
    std::copy(strs.begin(), strs.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (9990 lines omitted for brevity =P)

```
MRdeOWckfKy8GTFt0YmQMcM6SABJc934
XvdcatVsv6N9c1PzQGFFY6ZP943yIrUY
xpHzxUUyAizB6BfKldQzoePrm82PF1bn
kMUyPbflxk3yj3IToTFqYWnDq6aznKas
Ey0W5SF37VaeEY6PxWsBoxlNZTv9lOUn
iTx7jFRTHHW6TfYl7N3Hne4yu7kgAzp5
0ZamlaopjLyEvJbr6fzJPdXmjLOohtKh
6ZYeqj47nCMYKj0sCGl2IHm28FmvuH8h
oTDYRIA1trN1A2pQjsBwG3j9llzKIMhw
5zlpvSgTeLQ38eFWeSDoSY9IHEMHyzix
```

And note you may be surprised how fast this runs. There is quite a lot going on under the hood. Finally, this uses the C++11 random library, in particular the uniform distribution, which eliminates modulus-bias typically encountered with traditional `rand() % n` solutions for particular `n`.

Comment: I would rather have done e.g. `std::vector<std::string> strs{n}`, then used `std::generate` to set the entries directly, and do the same for the strings. Might maybe save a few cycles compared to by going through `std::back_inserter`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it was the reason I used reserve(). Presizing with actual instances fires all the constructors (which, given, for a std::string isn't much, but still). Ultimately is move-ctor vs move-assignment, so I'd be surprised if it made an difference. Would be fun to bench and see. **Edit**: I just caught the `generate` in your comment. That would be *very* interesting to see if it had a marked difference indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the [random number generators and distributions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) available in C++11.

e.g.,

```
const char alphanumeric[] = "0 .. 1A .. Za.. z";

std::default_random_engine rng;
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist (0, sizeof(alphanumeric) - 1);

...

for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    str += alphanumeric[dist(rng)];
```

I'd add that `vecStr.push_back(str)` might not be that expensive, as it may use a *move assignment* of the `std::string` object. `std::string` objects often have 'short string' optimizations (SSO) in their implementation as well.

```
vector<string> vecStr (N);
...
vecStr[index] = std::move(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do better than `O(mn)` (where `m` is the length of your strings (= 32 here) and `n` is the number of strings).

The reason is that the output size is `O(mn)`, and logically need to do at least `O(1)` work for each character in the output.

Note that your algorithm may be a little slower than `O(mn)`, since some reallocation of the string may happen. To prevent this, you can use [`string::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve):

```
int M = 32;
...
  string str;
  str.reserve(M);
  for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
...
```

But given that `M` is only 32, it's unlikely to make a significant difference.

**And, just for fun, here's a variation on you're code:**

```
int N = 10000, M = 32;
vector<string> vecStr;
string alphabet("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");
for (int index = 0; index < N; index++)
{
  string str;
  str.reserve(M);
  for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
  {
    str += alphabet[rand() % alphabet.length()];
  }
  vecStr.push_back(str);
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/vfiYVy).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using preallocated buffer for your random string.
Also, you might pregenerate some random chunks and permutate them.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an improvement in terms of alogrithmic effiiency, but I would suggest

```
void random_string(char *s, int len=32) {
static const char alphabet[] =
    "0123456789"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    s[i] = alphabet[rand() % (sizeof(alphabet) - 1)];
  }

 s[len] = '\0';
}
```